# JCheckBox centereing

Tags: java, swing

I have been searching for a while now, but couldnt find a solution so I have decided to ask here.

I am using Java Swing for my gui implementation of calculator. I have custom made layout(which works correctly 100%). I have added all buttons and all buttons are positioned correctly, always. Last component I have inserted is "Inv" and it is checkbox which I cant find a way to center it inside its area. I have tried putting it in panel,in panel with borderlayout.center, setting the horizontal and vertical text alignment, but nothing works.

```
invert = new JCheckBox("Inv");

invert.setBackground(Color.decode("#8DA336"));
invert.addActionListener(new CommandListener(this,"invert"));

container.add(invert, new RCPosition(5, 7));
```

This RCPosition is nothing more than object which says in which row and column this component is (nothing wrong with that).

[image: My calculator.]

Comment: how layout you use?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox is by default left-aligned. Try make it center-aligned:

```
invert = new JCheckBox("Inv");
invert.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
// styling and add to container
```

If it don't help, then you should publish your layout manager.

Comment: I dont know what happened, but this hasnt been working yesterday, but now it does. Thanx anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting it in a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout`, then add horizontal glue on the left and right.

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
final JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
jp.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
final JCheckBox jcb = new JCheckBox("inv");
jp.add(jcb);
jp.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

frame.getContentPane().add(jp);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

This is just one way to do it, `setHorizontalAlignment` should work as well.